# ckeditor related error- value is not a valid property

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I have that following error when trying to use ckeditor

> two-way binding is only supported for properties. 'Value' is not a valid property on 'CKEditorControl'

This is the related code:

```
 <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKeditor1" runat="server"
                    ToolbarSet="MyToolbarSet"
                    Value='<%# Bind("html") %>' EditorAreaCSS="/css/editor.css">
                </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

Any idea what it can be?

- I found one related post on ckeditor forum "Try changing value to text" - but it didn't help.
  He meant to change: Value='<%# Bind("html") to Value='<%# Bind("text"), right?

Answer (score 0):

With the CKEditor 3.x ASP.Net control, the code should be:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKeditor1" runat="server"
    ToolbarSet="MyToolbarSet"
    Text="<%# Bind('html') %>" ContentsCss="/css/editor.css">
</CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

where the property "Value" is changed to "Text" and the property "EditorAreaCSS" is changed to "ContentsCss".